# Show that the recursion $f(n) = 2f(n-1) + f(n-2)$ for $n \ge 2$ and $f(0) = 1, f(1) = 3$ is true.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> For $n \in \Bbb N$, let $f(n)$ be the number of paths that do not cross themselves in $\Bbb Z^2$ while taking $n$ steps. Let $(0,0)$ be the starting point, and let every step posses the form $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$ or $(0,1).$
>
> Show that this can be described by the recursion
>
> $f(n) = 2f(n-1) + f(n-2)$ for $n \ge 2$ and $f(0) = 1, f(1) = 3.$

This should work with induction, but I only come as far as to check the initial conditions.

$f(0) = 1$ is true. If we are allowed to take $0$ steps, there is exactly one path that exists (the "trivial" path we receive without moving at all).

$f(1) = 3$ is true. If we are allowed to take $1$ step, and we know that every step must posses the form $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$ or $(0,1)$, there exist $3$ different paths overall.

What seems much harder is finding the necessary induction step here. I could assume that

$f(n-1) = 2f(n-2) + f(n-3)$ is true, but what then?

Comment: What do you mean by "do not cross each other"? The set of paths not sharing any point except the starting one, or a property, that the path does not cross itself?

Comment: I believe it is meant that the path does not cross itself.

Comment: Then maybe "themselves" is better than "each other"

Comment: Changed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $F(n)$ the set of all paths of length $n$ satisfying your property,
so $F(n)$ is the set of all $p=(p_0,\ldots,p_n) \in {\big({\mathbb Z}^2\big)}^{n}$ such that
$p_0=0$, the $p_i$ are all distinct and $p_{i+1}-p_i\in \lbrace (\pm 1,0);(0,1) \rbrace$.

Let $A(n)=\lbrace p\in F(n) | p_1=(1,0) \rbrace$, $B(n)=\lbrace p\in F(n) | p_1=(-1,0) \rbrace$, and $C(n)=\lbrace p\in F(n) | p_1=(0,1) \rbrace$. Also, denote by $a(n),b(n),c(n)$ the number of elements in $A(n),B(n),C(n)$.

Then 
$$f(n)=a(n)+b(n)+c(n) \tag{1}$$

Putting $\psi(x,y)=(x,y-1)$, the map 
$(p_0,\ldots,p_n) \mapsto (\psi(p_1),\ldots,\psi(p_n))$ establishes a bijection between 
$C(n)$ and $F(n-1)$, so

$$c(n)=f(n-1)\tag{2}$$

Similarly, putting $\phi(x,y)=(-x,y)$,  the map 
$(p_0,\ldots,p_n) \mapsto (\phi(p_0),\ldots,\phi(p_n))$ establishes a bijection between 
$A(n)$ and $B(n)$, so

$$b(n)=a(n)\tag{3}$$

Combining (1),(2) and (3) we deduce

$$
f(n)=2a(n)+f(n-1) \tag{4}
$$

Next, let $D(n)=\lbrace p\in A(n) | p_2=(2,0) \rbrace$ and $E(n)=\lbrace p\in A(n) | p_1=(1,1) \rbrace$. Also, denote by $d(n),e(n)$ the number of elements in $D(n),E(n)$.
We then have

$$
a(n)=d(n)+e(n)\tag{5}
$$

The map $(p_0,\ldots,p_n) \mapsto (\psi(p_1),\ldots,\psi(p_n))$ establishes a bijection between $D(n)$ and $A(n-1)$, so

$$d(n)=a(n-1)\tag{6}$$

Putting $\rho(x,y)=(x-1,y-1)$, The map $(p_0,\ldots,p_n) \mapsto (\rho(p_2),\ldots,\psi(p_n))$ establishes a bijection between $D(n)$ and $F(n-2)$, so

$$e(n)=f(n-2)\tag{7}$$

Combining (5),(6) and (7) we deduce

$$
a(n)=a(n-1)+f(n-2) \tag{8}
$$

So $f(n-2)=a(n)-a(n-1)$, but using (4) twice we have $a(n)=\frac{f(n)-f(n-1)}{2}$
and $a(n-1)=\frac{f(n-1)-f(n-2)}{2}$, so $f(n-2)=\frac{f(n)-2f(n-1)+f(n-2)}{2}$ and your formula follows.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the paths have the characteristic, that the only problem is making an inverse step to the last one. Otherwise you are moving in a positive direction along one of the axis and can never return back. Therefore for the induction it is sufficient to lay these conditions:

Lets presume that $f(n-1)$ describes all paths of length $n-1$ and let $f(n-2)$ describe the number of paths with length $n-1$, where the last step taken was the one without inversion. These paths can be extended by all three possible moves.

So, the get the next number of paths, we take $2f(n-1)$, where we extended any path by making the non-invertible step and the other one possible. But, the paths ending in the non-invertible can be extended by all three of them, so we add it $f(n-2)$.

And we get that now $f(n)$ are all paths of length $n$, and $f(n-1)$ is the number of paths of length n ending with the non-invertible step. Induction holds.